# Check if a string is null or contains value in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT coding and i am trying to check if certain field is null or no.
In case that it null, it will fill in with number of '1' value and in case that is not null, to case the value.
I start writing the code but i can't run it at all, i believe i miss something. code below. thank you.

```
<xsl:variable name="SumLength" select="'TSALengthX'">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="SumLength != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="SumLength"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues:

1. If you're populating a variable by using the `select` attribute,
   then the `xsl:variable` element needs to be empty:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="SumLength" select="'TSALengthX'"/>
   ```
2. Your variable contains (or would contain) the **string** `"TSALengthX"`;
   if you want it to contain the **node** `TSALengthX`, you must define it as:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="SumLength" select="TSALength"/>
   ```

I am not sure why you need this variable at all: why don't you simply test the `TSALengthX` node directly?